# Partial view does not render on posting the data from another partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view "Home" inside which I render 2 partial views _P1 & _p2.
Following is my code in Home View:

```
<div>
        <div>
            @Html.Partial("_P1")
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.Partial("_p2")
        </div>
</div>
```

I have a textbox and a submit button on _P1 and just a label on _P2, when I click submit I want the data to be posted but the user to be redirected to the same view containing _P1 & _P2. But _P2 does not get rendered after submit.

Code on _P1:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_P1", "Home", new AjaxOptions(), new { Id = "_P1form" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
}
<input type="button" value="Save Form Data" class="save-button" onclick="submitform();"/>
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

just use viewbag.  Set it on the controller depending on the step you are on and in the view

```
@if(!ViewBag.PostBack){
    @Html.Partial("_p2")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Render the first partial they way you are doing but the second partial view can be rendered when the button is clicked. Update your begin for using the following bit of code.

In the AjaxOptions can you do the following

```
@using (
   Ajax.BeginForm("**Action Name from your controller**"
                   , "**Controller Name**"
                   , new  AjaxOptions
                    { 
                      HttpMethod ="Get", *// this can be get or post*
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, *// this will replace the content of the div. you can use the others like InsertAfter", "InsertBefore", or "Replace"*
                      UpdateTargetId="**Name of the div where you want to write the content**"
                    }
                 )
{

<div id="**div to be replaced**">
</div>

}
```

check out the URL which describes about other options available with ajax options method.[AjaxOptions Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Interesting one would be onBegin and onComplete if you desire to show a progress indicator